# How can DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH be unset for launchd processes?

Tags: osx, apache-httpd, php

### The Skinny

I built PHP as an apache module (libphp56.so) and linked it against MacPorts' libcurl. However, httpd fails when launching (via launchd) if libphp56.so is loaded, printing a library version mismatch error.

### The Fat

I ran PHP's configure script with `--with-curl=/opt/local` to link it with /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (provided by MacPorts). That copy of libcurl is version 9.0.0, but dyld claims that version 7.0.0 is being loaded, which happens to be the version of /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib. For now, I'm assuming the latter is being loaded.

`apachectl` calls `launchctl` to run httpd. If run directly, httpd loads libphp56.so and runs without error.

Here's some relevant info from the command line (whitespace added for readability):

> ```
> $ sudo -s
> # apachectl configtest
> httpd: Syntax error on line 174 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: 
> Cannot load libexec/apache2/libphp56.so into server: 
> dlopen(/Library/WebServer/libexec/apache2/libphp56.so, 10): 
> Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /Library/WebServer/libexec/apache2/libphp56.so
> Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp56.so requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
>
> # /usr/sbin/httpd
> # ps -ax -O gid | grep /usr/sbin/httpd
>  6878     0   ??  Ss     0:00.22 /usr/sbin/httpd
>  6901    70   ??  S      0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd
>  6907     0 s008  S+     0:00.00 grep --color=auto /usr/sbin/httpd
> # kill -TERM 6878
>
> # otool -L /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib | grep libcurl
> /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
>     /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
>
> # otool -L /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib | grep libcurl 
> /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
>     /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
>
> # otool -L /Library/WebServer/libexec/apache2/libphp56.so | grep libcurl
>     /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
>
> # echo "x${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}x"
> xx
> # grep -r 'DYLD_.*_PATH' /etc
> # launchctl getenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
> ```

The launchd.plist for httpd is fairly basic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>XPC_SERVICES_UNAVAILABLE</key>
      <string>1</string>
    </dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
      <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.apache.httpd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/sbin/httpd</string>
      <string>-D</string>
      <string>FOREGROUND</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Setting the [dyld](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/dyld/osx-10.10.php) reporting environment variables `DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE`, `DYLD_PRINT_ENV` and `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` reveals launchd sets DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib is loaded.

> ```
> # DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=~/httpd.log DYLD_PRINT_ENV=1 DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 apachectl configtest
> # grep -P 'curl|DYLD_' ~/httpd.log
> DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/Users/Capra/httpd.log
> DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
> DYLD_PRINT_ENV=1
> DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
> DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/Users/Capra/httpd.log
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
> DYLD_PRINT_ENV=1
> dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
> # echo > ~/http.log
> # DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=~/httpd.log DYLD_PRINT_ENV=1 DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
> ^C
> # grep -P 'curl|DYLD_' ~/httpd.log
> DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/Users/Capra/httpd.log
> DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
> DYLD_PRINT_ENV=1
> dyld: loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
> dyld: unloaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
> dyld: loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
> ```

Note that libcurl isn't the only library to suffer this issue. While troubleshooting, I left out PHP's curl extension as part of the build and got a similar message regarding libxml.

## The Question(s)

How can I unset `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` for httpd when run via launchd? What are the security ramifications?

### Attempted Solutions

- <kbd>launchctl unsetenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH</kbd>
- setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in org.apache.httpd.plist.
- have org.apache.httpd.plist run a wrapper for httpd that sets `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

### Non-Solutions

While I could link against the system libcurl, I'm looking for a way to have PHP run with updated components; linking /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib is only a last resort. Avoiding launchd entirely, not including the affected PHP extensions/libraries in the build and replacing the system libcurl are also considered non-solutions. I'd almost consider having a wrapper that would move.

### System Info

- OS: Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite.
- Web server: Apache 2.4.16
- PHP 5.6.31

Comment: Did you try `env` in your launcher? Something like `env -iDYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`? Did you try to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib` in your launcher (in the EnvironmentVariables section)?

Comment: @xhienne: un/setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to anything in the launchd.plist and wrapper by any method fails. Also, I don't want to prepend "/opt/local/lib" to the path as there are system libraries I must use over the MacPorts ones (httpd loads /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib, so PHP must use the same).